# @FetchRequest + case-insensitive sorting - SwiftUI & CoreData

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swiftui, nsfetchrequest

I have a list of items being sorted by name.

I can create a fetch request which is case insensitive as follows:

```
struct ContentView: View {
   
   var fetchRequest: FetchRequest<Item>
   
   init() {
      fetchRequest = FetchRequest<Item>(entity: Item.entity(), sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true, selector: #selector(NSString.caseInsensitiveCompare(_:)))
      ])
   }
   
   var body: some View {
      // content
   }
   
}
```

Though I would prefer to do it like:

```
struct ContentView: View {
   
   @FetchRequest(entity: Item.entity(), sortDescriptors: [
      NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Item.name, ascending: true) // <-- can I add a selector here?
   ]) var items: FetchedResults<Item>
   
   var body: some View {
      // content
   }
   
}
```

Can @FetchRequest take a selector as an argument?

Going off the docs, NSSortDescriptor seems to take an argument called `localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare`, but I couldn't get it to work or find any examples online.

Comment: try `NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true, selector:  #selector(NSString.localizedStandardCompare))`. Of course you can use `localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare` as well if you would like to. Note that `localizedStandardCompare` is also diacritic insensitive.

Comment: Ah! Switching `keyPath: \Item.name` with `keyPath: "name"` worked.
I should have noticed that difference. Cheers!

Comment: Actually it was `key: "name"` (incase anybody stumbles on this one day...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass NSString `localizedStandardCompare` method to the selector property:

```
NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true, selector: #selector(NSString.localizedStandardCompare))
```